# Redirect is not working for react-router in a single component

Tags: javascript, html, express, react-router

I have set react router to redirect from "/" route to a custom route /:city/posts , but the redirect is not working as expected, onClick of button page refresh's , I have it setup working fine in other componts, not sure what is the issue

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-sammet-eitqr

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Form,
  Container,
  Button,
  DropdownButton,
  Dropdown
} from "react-bootstrap";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const Location = () => {
  let [city, setCity] = useState("");
  let [acceptedTOS, setAcceptedTOS] = useState(false);

  const handleFormSubmit = () => {
    // if (city !== "" && acceptedTOS === true) {
    return <Redirect to="/city/posts" />;
    // }
  };

  console.log("city ====", city, "acceptedTOS===", acceptedTOS);
  return (
    <Container>
      <Form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
        <h3>Select a City</h3>

        <br />

        <DropdownButton
          id="dropdown-basic-button"
          title={city !== "" ? city : "Canada"}
        >
                </DropdownButton>

        <br />
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Check
            required
            name="terms"
            label="I have read and agreed to follow TOS"
            onChange={() => {
              setAcceptedTOS(true);
            }}
            // isInvalid={!!errors.terms}
            // feedback={errors.terms}
            id="validationFormik0"
          />

          <Button type="submit">Submit form</Button>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Location;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a state for redirect,

```
const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false)
```

Add `e.preventDefault()` in `handleFormSubmit`,

```
const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setRedirect(true) //set redirect to ture
};
```

Finally in your return you can redirect,

```
return (
    <Container>
      {redirect && <Redirect to="/:city/posts" />}
      ...
    </Container>
)
```

Comment: Sir why did you choose to redirect in return rather than the handle form or another function inside the component

Comment: `render` function is a good position to redirect based on state value, because when state changes component will get re-render.